# How can I use IfElse or Case_When to solve an R problem where output needs to be put into 2 columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Description**

I am trying to extract three digits from each value in the Pitcnt column. (See Output table). The first value (1 or 2 digits) is at the start of the string, the second value is before the dash, and the third value is after the dash. The second and third values are always just one digit. I have tried to find a solution (using dplyr) in StackOverflow that uses either the IF statement or the Case_When, but couldn't. If one exists, I would appreciate its URL.

**Output**

[image]

**Dput Code**

```
structure(list(Pitcnt = c("12 (3-2)", "7 (0-1)", "3 (0-2)", 
"8 (3-2)", "5 (2-2)", "7 (3-2)", "1 (0-0)", "2 (0-1)", "5 (1-2)", 
"10 (3-2)")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

**Code I've Tried**

I tried to get it to work using both IfElse and Case_When, but could not get either to do what I want because, each result of the IF statement requires that data be put into two different columns (X and Y) at the same time.

The code below shows how it can be done without using either IfElse or Case_When.

```
pc8 <- pc %>%
  filter(nchar(Pitcnt) == 8) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(substr(Pitcnt,5,5))) %>%
  mutate(y = as.numeric(substr(Pitcnt,7,7)))

pc7 <- pc %>%   
  filter(nchar(Pitcnt) == 7) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(substr(Pitcnt,4,4))) %>%
  mutate(y = as.numeric(substr(Pitcnt,6,6)))
pc7
```

This pseudocode shows what I want to do:
If nchar(Pitcnt) = 8 then put the digit before the dash in X and the digit after the dash into Y, else if nchar(Pitcnt) = 7 then put the digit before the dash in X and the digit after the dash into Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   separate(Pitcnt, c("Pitches", "X", "Y"), remove = FALSE,
            convert = TRUE, extra = "drop")

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Pitcnt   Pitches     X     Y
   <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
 1 12 (3-2)      12     3     2
 2 7 (0-1)        7     0     1
 3 3 (0-2)        3     0     2
 4 8 (3-2)        8     3     2
 5 5 (2-2)        5     2     2
 6 7 (3-2)        7     3     2
 7 1 (0-0)        1     0     0
 8 2 (0-1)        2     0     1
 9 5 (1-2)        5     1     2
10 10 (3-2)      10     3     2
```

Base R:

```
cbind(df, read.table(text = gsub("\\D+", " ", df$Pitcnt), 
     col.names = c("Pitches", "X", "Y")))

     Pitcnt Pitches X Y
1  12 (3-2)      12 3 2
2   7 (0-1)       7 0 1
3   3 (0-2)       3 0 2
4   8 (3-2)       8 3 2
5   5 (2-2)       5 2 2
6   7 (3-2)       7 3 2
7   1 (0-0)       1 0 0
8   2 (0-1)       2 0 1
9   5 (1-2)       5 1 2
10 10 (3-2)      10 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `gsub` with regex matching. The regex matches the following `"[pattern 1: digits]-space-[pattern 2: digits after opening paranthesis]-dash-[pattern 3: digits before closing paranthesis]"`:

```
str.regex.pattern <- "(\\d+)\\s\\((\\d+)\\-(\\d+)\\)"

pc %>% mutate(
    pitches = gsub(str.regex.pattern, "\\1", Pitcnt), 
    x = gsub(str.regex.pattern, "\\2", Pitcnt), 
    y = gsub(str.regex.pattern, "\\3", Pitcnt)
)

# output
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Pitcnt   pitches x     y    
   <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1 12 (3-2) 12      3     2    
 2 7 (0-1)  7       0     1    
 3 3 (0-2)  3       0     2    
 4 8 (3-2)  8       3     2    
 5 5 (2-2)  5       2     2    
 6 7 (3-2)  7       3     2    
 7 1 (0-0)  1       0     0    
 8 2 (0-1)  2       0     1    
 9 5 (1-2)  5       1     2    
10 10 (3-2) 10      3     2
```

Comment: when I ran your code, the first, second, and last rows of the output were fine, however, in the other rows, in each row the data in all four columns was identical and the same as is in the Pitcnt column.. Any idea why?

Comment: @Metsfan Then the regex pattern fails for these rows because they deviate from the pattern in your sample. Are you sure you correctly copied the regex pattern? If you can tell me the overall general pattern (or give me some more examples), we can improve the current solution together. Otherwise, other solutions might do the job.

Comment: I copied your Regex pattern correctly. Maybe it is an RStudio problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(test = stringr::str_extract_all(Pitcnt, '\\d+'),  # extract all numbers
         test = lapply(test,setNames,c("Pitches","X","Y"))) %>% #set the names
  tidyr::unnest_wider(test) #unnest list column 

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Pitcnt   Pitches X     Y    
   <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1 12 (3-2) 12      3     2    
 2 7 (0-1)  7       0     1    
 3 3 (0-2)  3       0     2    
 4 8 (3-2)  8       3     2    
 5 5 (2-2)  5       2     2    
 6 7 (3-2)  7       3     2    
 7 1 (0-0)  1       0     0    
 8 2 (0-1)  2       0     1    
 9 5 (1-2)  5       1     2    
10 10 (3-2) 10      3     2
```